# Error in my stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I created a stored procedure as follows:

```
create procedure [dbo].[ModifCodMedecin] @Table nvarchar(10),@Code nvarchar(7) as
DECLARE @rqt as NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @rqt = 'UPDATE' + @Table + 'SET '+  @Code + ' = Med.New_Code_exploitation from ' + @Table + 
'  inner join Medecin_New Med on ' + @Table + '.' + @Code + ' = Med.[Ancien_Code])'
exec (@rqt)
```

When I executed the above, an error is produced:

> ModifCodMedecin 'Table','code'
>       Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Debugging Tip : check what is in @rqt before executing i.e. `print @rqt` before  `exec (@rqt)`. copy what is printed and execute it manually.

Comment: you have an extra `)` at the end `Med.[Ancien_Code])'`

Comment: The problem is the extra ) and it lacks a space between 'Update  '+ @Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ModifCodMedecin] @Table NVARCHAR(10)
    ,@Code NVARCHAR(7)
AS
DECLARE @rqt AS NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @rqt = 'UPDATE ' + @Table 
                     + ' SET ' + @Code 
                     + ' = Med.New_Code_exploitation from ' + @Table 
                     + '  inner join Medecin_New Med on ' + @Table + '.' + @Code 
                     + ' = Med.[Ancien_Code]'

EXEC (@rqt)
```

You had a few missing spaces, one after `UPDATE` and one before `SET`. As well as the additional parenthesis at the end.